# How to hand off to another controller in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, http-redirect

I'm new to CodeIgniter and have created a controller that talks to a few views and models.

Once my controller finishes doing its things (lets say this controller handles logins and registrations), how does it hand off to another controller (to handle a user's interface and so forth)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Appears that I was just doing it wrong.   I was getting errors like:

> Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at [path]

And such.  I was doing things in the wrong order.

My solution was to just fix the code and user redirect().

Answer (score -1):

You could include the file containing the controller, then make a new instance of the controller:

```
<?php
require_once("path/to/other_controller.php");
class MainController extends CI_Controller {
    public function index() {
        // Logic here...
        $other_controller = new OtherController();
        $other_controller->moreLogic();
    }
}
?>
```

But if you need to use multiple controllers, you're doing something wrong. You should be using multiple models which each handle their appropriate logic (in separate files, too!). The user interface should be handled in the views, anyways, even if that means that logic has to be done in the views.

Comment: My entire web app would be managed by one controller?  I assumed it would have separate controllers for distinct purposes/sections of the app.

Comment: No, you're correct there. Rather, the controllers shouldn't ever reference each other. I meant "if you need to use multiple controllers **for one page**, then you're doing something wrong." It would certainly be chaotic using only one controller for everything :P